# Is there an equivalent to PHP's htmlentities in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

My ColdFusion app is required to create Word 2003 documents, with complex data like images (only a small text portion needs to be dynamic, though). To let this happen, I've saved a Word document that I use as a template in "single-file HTML" (read: MHT), and I insert data at specific points in the file from my ColdFusion scripts.

Passed the [quoted-printable cleverness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) the MHT file format dragged me into, it actually works pretty well. The only problem is that I need special (non-ASCII) characters in my Word documents, and apparently, both my app and Word use a different, non-Unicode encoding.

Now that I have my template and my program, I'm not very enthusiastic about changing their respective encodings. Another requirement is that users should be able to submit new templates, so I can't just change the template's encoding because newer templates will have the same problem.

I thought the simplest way to solve the problem would be to use a function like PHP's `htmlentities`, that converts every non-ASCII character in an HTML entity. Does ColdFusion have such a function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[XmlFormat](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e62.html) will convert ASCII characters in the 159-255 range along with the standard html entities.

Answer (score 1):

You want [HTMLEditFormat](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7847.html)

Comment: Does it exist with ColdFusion 8? Besides, it doesn't look like it encodes non-ASCII characters, just HTML reserved characters.

Comment: It is, but in that case, I don't know of an all encompassing function, but you could search through the characters and find any with an asc() result that is less than 33 or higher than 126 and replace it with the html entity

Comment: I could, but I'd have to build a mapping between the char codes and the entities, which looks like a long and painful job.

Comment: no you just get the asc code: ex: asc("a"), then use that result in the entity: &###asc("a")#;  all chars have an HTML entity equivalent of &#[number here];

Comment: Is it certain that my encoding matches the one HTML uses?

Comment: ascii codes are ascii codes no matter what platform you are on.  ASCII is a standard.

Comment: I was trying to turn non-ASCII codes into HTML entities so they work no matter the encoding.

Comment: every character has an ASCII numerical equivalent.  You want characters in a certain ASCII range to be replaced.

Comment: ASCII is standard, but not all characters are ASCII. `é` is not an ASCII character, nor is `à`, nor is `œ`, nor is `他`. All characters have an Unicode numerical equivalent, but Unicode and ASCII are two very different things. Since I am not using Unicode because I am maintning an old application, I do have to worry about encodings.